# In BibTeX say: One or more errors occured! please check the options!, what can I do?

Tags: bibtex, errors

When I try to run Bibtex a window error is open  that say 
One or more errors occured!
please check the options!

I do not understand!, What can I do?

Thanks 
Mario

Comment: Apparently, miktex users [sometimes see this](http://www.winshell.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=331&forum=1&order=DESC) if their installation is broken. (I know nothing about miktex myself, but I do know how to google.)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, the problem was the path of the executable files

Comment: @Mario: very nice that you posted the solution.