# BibTeX work in Miktex 2.7, but in version 2.8 does not work

Tags: bibtex, miktex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In BibTeX say: One or more errors occured!  please check the options!, what can I do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5651/in-bibtex-say-one-or-more-errors-occured-please-check-the-options-what-can-i)

In a computer with Miktex 2.7 a run bibtex works very well, but in another computer that I have instaled MikTex 2.8 does not work. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi Mario, please consider to edit your original question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5651/in-bibtex-say-one-or-more-errors-occured-please-check-the-options-what-can-i instead of posting a new one for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the problem was the path of the executable files